# change image alignment jquery

Tags: jquery, image, alignment

My CMS automatically adds `align="left"` to the images, can I change the image alignment from left to center

this:

`<img src="image.jpg" width="360" height="540" align="left">`

to:

`<img src="image.jpg" width="360" height="540" align="center">`

with jquery / javascript. I have looked and I can't find anything.

Thanks

Comment: $("img").attr("align","center")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course... Just change `align` attribute

```
$("img").attr("align","center");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/86Zg9/

Comment: Yeah I looked but couldn't find it. Thanks for that mesiesta, and IamStalker

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(img).attr('align', 'absmiddle');
```